# Whatsapp like notification in android wear

Tags: android, wear-os

I need to achieve notification in android wear like in whatsapp where each conversation is a list and sliding to the right allows the user to reply to the respective conversation. I tried stacking from the android developers example but it only displays messages as is. How could I set more than 1 message and respective action like in whatsapp?

Edit:

```
  NotificationCompat.WearableExtender wearOptions =
  new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender()
   .setHintHideIcon(true);

  String replyLabel = mXmppConnectionService.getResources().getString(R.string.wear_reply);
  RemoteInput remoteInput = new RemoteInput.Builder(EXTRA_VOICE_REPLY)
                .setLabel(replyLabel)
                .build();

 Intent replyIntent = new Intent(mXmppConnectionService, XmppConnectionService.class);
 PendingIntent replyPendingIntent =
 PendingIntent.getActivity(mXmppConnectionService, 0, replyIntent,
                                      PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);

 NotificationCompat.Action action =
                  new NotificationCompat.Action.Builder(R.mipmap.ic_launcher,
                        "reply to", replyPendingIntent)
                        .addRemoteInput(remoteInput)
                        .build();
 final Builder mBuilder;
 mBuilder.setDefaults(0);
 mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_notification);
 mBuilder.setPriority(getPriority());
 mBuilder.setDeleteIntent(createDeleteIntent());
 mBuilder.setLights(0xff00FF00, 2000, 3000)
    .extend(wearOptions)
    .extend(new NotificationCompat.WearableExtender().addAction(action));

 final Notification notification = mBuilder.build();
            notificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: I did not make a separate wearable module but instead, I'm just sending the notification to wear. The code is added anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are missing essentially three different things:

1. you are not calling `setGroup("GROP_NAME")` on your `NotificationBuilder`
2. Notifications that belong to the same group must have different ids.  If you notify always with the same id, `NOTIFICATION_ID` in your case, ste stacking will not work
3. you want a different `replyPendingIntent` for each notification, otherwise your pending intent will refer to the last notification notified. Instead of hard-coding `0`, pass a different value for each notification.

The rest looks good,

Comment: Thank you for pointing it out. So, I will have to assign different notification id to each conversation and then notify it?

Comment: a different id for conversation and pending intent

Comment: Thank you again. gonna take some time to make the changes. Will let you know the result as soon as I do the changes.